# Protractor : why (browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);')does not work in one project but already in another?

Tags: javascript, scroll, protractor, asynccallback, jasmine-node

I use:

```
Chrome: 80.0.3987.132
Windows 10
Node 12.14.1
Protractor 5.4.3
Java 1.8.0_241
jasmine 3.5.0
webdriver-manager 3.141.59
```

I have problem with scroll_down in protractor. When I use:

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);').then(function () {
console.log('++++++SCROLLED Down+++++');
```

it works properly. (e.g: onet.pl, wp.pl)

When I need use this command in my project I get:
FA Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.

Message:

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Stack:
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)

I tried different command:
getPageTimeout: 7000, allScriptsTimeout: 7000 and other.

My conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
// getPageTimeout: 7000,
// directConnect: true,
// allScriptsTimeout: 7000,
capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome', 
// 'max-duration': 300000,
// 'command-timeout': 300000,
// 'idle-duration': 30000,
},
jasmineNodeOpts: {
showColors: true,
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
},
framework : 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js']
}
```

Part of spec.js:

```
describe ('log in ', function(){
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
// browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2000) 
it ('enter login and password ', function()
{
// jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 100000;
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.get('https://xyz.pop.pl/');

// browser.getTitle().then(function(title){
//     browser.sleep(5000)
// })

element(by.xpath("//*[@id='option-single']/label/div[1]")).click()
browser.driver.sleep(5000);

browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,10000);').then(function () {
console.log('++++++SCROLLED Down+++++');
});
browser.driver.sleep(10000);
```

Do you have any ideas where is the mistake?Thanks :)

Comment: Can you see click before the scroll working correctly?

Comment: Yes,  click on this element ( //*[@id='option-single']/label/div[1]) is ok, i need scroll down, because i have other element below to click and it's my problem.